# how to access signed request on second page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My Two page facebook application contains

index.php
welcome.php

On index.php

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

works fine and i can get page id

but when i click on welcome page, and try to get page id, 
$signed_request does not fetch page id.

```
[algorithm] => xxxx
[code] => xxxxx    
[issued_at] => xxxxxx
[user_id] => xxxxxxx
```

got this but couldn't get page id

Comment: possible duplicate of [FB Authentication goes from Fanpages to app page and not back to fanpage](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9381869/fb-authentication-goes-from-fanpages-to-app-page-and-not-back-to-fanpage)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook app with multiple PHP pages](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6458417/facebook-app-with-multiple-php-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get `$signed_request`on the first page. You should save it in a session if you want to use it on another page.

Comment: how to get this using curl or JSON?

Comment: i'm new to this platform plz help. i need to know

Comment: do you need help saving it in a session?